# Running powershell scripts by drag-n-drop file or folder on it

Tags: windows-7, powershell, shell-script, drag-and-drop

Is there any way of running a powershell script by drag-n-dropping a file on it (just like you would drag-n-drop a file on a .exe file)? It would be also nice to be able to do the same thing with folders...

Comment: See this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file  Once you get it to start by double clicking, I think the drag and drop just auto-magically happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a Windows Explorer shortcut (In Explorer right click -> new -> shortcut). Then right-click on your shortcut and open the Properties dialog box. In the Target field enter something like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -noprofile -file C:\yourscriptdirectory\yourscript.ps1
```

Whether you need the `-noexit` or `-noprofile` options is up to you, take a look at [the help](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847736.aspx) to decide.

Now when you drop a file (or folder) onto this shortcut, explorer will magically pass it as the first argument to your script.

Answer (score 0):

The above shortcut works when you drop one file on the shortcut file.  The fully qualified filename will be passed as the first parameter of the called PowerShell script.

**You may also drop multiple files.**  These can either be picked up as $Args array parameters or in a named parameter by using the [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)] specification in your PowerShell script.

**See my summary on Stack Overflow at** [Dragging and Dropping Files onto a PowerShell Script --- Additional Information and Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655089/15945124)

- The posting also describes how to use a .BAT file instead of a Shortcut file to pass dropped file names to a PowerShell script.
- In a [2nd posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67813984/15945124) I give a way to have the PowerShell script also expand and process files in any dropped directories.